# iOS - NSURLSession not working the second time

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UIView` that contains a progress bar. What I want to do is simple, I have a button, user clicks that button, app downloads file and show progress in progress bar. I am able to do this when the user clicks the download button the first time. But when the user clicks the second time to download again, `NSURLSession` delegates are not called.

My UIView .m

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self configure];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self configure];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)configure
{
    [self createSpinner];
    [self createProgressBar];

    NSArray *URLs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
    self.docDirectoryURL = [URLs objectAtIndex:0];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"com.tinkytickles"];
    sessionConfiguration.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1;
    self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration
                                                 delegate:self
                                            delegateQueue:nil];
}

-(void)createSpinner
{
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.5f]];

    spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [self addSubview:spinner];
    [spinner setColor:original_new_dark_grey];
    [spinner setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [spinner setCenter:CGPointMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width/2, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height/2)];
    [spinner setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];
    [spinner startAnimating];
}

-(void)createProgressBar
{
    self.progressBar = [[TYMProgressBarView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 15)];
    [self.progressBar setBarBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.progressBar setBarBorderColor:original_new_dark_grey];
    [self.progressBar setBarFillColor:original_new_dark_grey];
    [self.progressBar setBarBorderWidth:1.0f];
    [self addSubview:self.progressBar];
    [self.progressBar setCenter:CGPointMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width/2, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height/2)];
    [self.progressBar setHidden:YES];

    self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.progressBar.frame.origin.x, self.progressBar.frame.origin.y - 30, self.progressBar.frame.size.width, 25)];
    [self.label setText:NSLocalizedString(locDownloading, nil)];
    [self.label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [self.label setTextColor:original_new_dark_grey];
    [self.label setFont:quicksand_14];
    [self addSubview:self.label];
    [self.label setHidden:YES];
}

-(void)showProgressBarWithProgress:(CGFloat)progress withText:(NSString *)text
{
    [spinner setHidden:YES];

    [self.label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(locDownloadingAt, nil), text]];
    [self.label setHidden:NO];
    [self.progressBar setHidden:NO];
    [self.progressBar setProgress:progress];
}


-(void)stopAnimating
{
    [spinner stopAnimating];
}

-(void)startDownloadingURL:(PromoterDownloadInfo *)downloadInfo
{
    info = downloadInfo;

    if (!info.isDownloading)
    {
        if (info.taskIdentifier == -1)
        {
            info.downloadTask = [self.session downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:info.downloadSource]];
            info.taskIdentifier = info.downloadTask.taskIdentifier;
            [info.downloadTask resume];
        }
        else
        {
            info.downloadTask = [self.session downloadTaskWithResumeData:info.taskResumeData];
            [info.downloadTask resume];
            info.taskIdentifier = info.downloadTask.taskIdentifier;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [info.downloadTask cancelByProducingResumeData:^(NSData *resumeData) {
            if (resumeData != nil) {
                info.taskResumeData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:resumeData];
            }
        }];
    }

    info.isDownloading = !info.isDownloading;
}

-(void)stopDownload:(PromoterDownloadInfo *)downloadInfo
{
    if (!info.isDownloading)
    {
        if (info.taskIdentifier == -1)
        {
            info.downloadTask = [self.session downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:info.downloadSource]];
        }
        else
        {
            info.downloadTask = [self.session downloadTaskWithResumeData:info.taskResumeData];
        }

        info.taskIdentifier = info.downloadTask.taskIdentifier;
        [info.downloadTask resume];
        info.isDownloading = YES;
    }

    [self stopAnimating];
    [self removeFromSuperview];
}

#pragma mark - NSURLSession Delegate method implementation

-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location
{
    NSError *error;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSString *destinationFilename = downloadTask.originalRequest.URL.lastPathComponent;
    NSURL *destinationURL = [self.docDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:destinationFilename];

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[destinationURL path]]) {
        [fileManager removeItemAtURL:destinationURL error:nil];
    }

    BOOL success = [fileManager copyItemAtURL:location
                                        toURL:destinationURL
                                        error:&error];

    if (success) {
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            [self stopAnimating];
            [self removeFromSuperview];
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Unable to copy temp file. Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}


-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error{
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Download completed with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Download finished successfully.");
    }
}


-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
{
    if (totalBytesExpectedToWrite == NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown) {
        NSLog(@"Unknown transfer size");
    }
    else
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            info.downloadProgress = (double)totalBytesWritten / (double)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
            [self showProgressBarWithProgress:info.downloadProgress withText:info.fileTitle];
        });
    }
}


-(void)URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    // Check if all download tasks have been finished.
    [self.session getTasksWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *dataTasks, NSArray *uploadTasks, NSArray *downloadTasks) {

        if ([downloadTasks count] == 0) {
            if (appDelegate.backgroundTransferCompletionHandler != nil) {
                // Copy locally the completion handler.
                void(^completionHandler)() = appDelegate.backgroundTransferCompletionHandler;

                // Make nil the backgroundTransferCompletionHandler.
                appDelegate.backgroundTransferCompletionHandler = nil;

                [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                    // Call the completion handler to tell the system that there are no other background transfers.
                    completionHandler();

                    // Show a local notification when all downloads are over.
                    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
                    localNotification.alertBody = NSLocalizedString(locDownloadComplete, nil);
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
                }];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

I use this UIView like this:

```
PromoterDownloadInfo *info = [[PromoterDownloadInfo alloc] initWithFileTitle:self.title andDownloadSource:@"https://www.mywebsite.com/file.zip"];
PromotersDownloadView *downloadView = [[PromotersDownloadView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:downloadView];
[downloadView startDownloadingURL:info];
```

The first time I clicked the download button it works great. The second time `NSURLSession` only `didCompleteWithError` method gets called. Here is what I get from log the second time:

```
2016-05-12 00:50:47.440 APP[32990:1230071] A background URLSession with identifier com.app already exists!
2016-05-12 00:50:50.614 APP[32990:1230386] Download finished successfully.
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried to create `NSURLSessionConfiguration` only once but this way no delegate method gets called. What should I do?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha I do not get any error. I get the log I provided in my question. The second time `-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite` is not called

Comment: @SausageMachine but the info gets created every time the user clicks the download button, so isDownloading is always initially NO

Comment: @Rob If I have 10 files I want to download. Do I create 10 background sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> The first time I clicked the download button it works great. ... Here is what I get from log the second time:
>
> ```
> 2016-05-12 00:50:47.440 APP[32990:1230071] A background URLSession with  identifier com.app already exists!<br />
> ```

That error is pointing out that you want to instantiate only one background `NSURLSession` for a given identifier (and you generally only need/want a single background session). If you were going to instantiate multiple ones, you'd give them unique identifiers, but handling background sessions is complicated enough without unnecessarily having multiple sessions. I'd suggest that you only want a single background session.

You said:

> I tried to create `NSURLSessionConfiguration` only once but this way no delegate method gets called.

Yes, you should have one session configuration. And, just as importantly, only one background session object.

I suspect that there's an issue with your delegate object not being able to keep track of which view it should be updating. Or perhaps you lost reference to your session object and your reference was `nil`. It could be a couple of different things, and it's hard to know without seeing how you did this.

I'd suggest moving this session configuration code out of the view, and have some shared instance that you can reference anywhere (e.g. a singleton works well, so you can instantiate it from wherever it's first needed, whether from a view or from the app delegate's `handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession` method).

The only challenge then is how to keep track of which views are keeping track of which network requests. Do you want to have a single view that will keep track of all incomplete requests, regardless of when this view is instantiated? If so, you can use `NSNotificationCenter` notifications (that way, any view that wants to be notified of progress updates can just observe your custom notification). Or does a given view only care about requests that you initiated from that view?In that case, you might maintain dictionary that maps `taskIdentifier` values to which view or object needs to know about the status updates (what way you can have your session object keep track of which views care about which tasks). It just depends upon your app's requirements.